# .htaccess redirects and the logic of paths

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, alias, mod-alias

I ran into a problem redirecting some old urls to new ones locations

The problems involved urls like these:

```
1) RedirectMatch permanent  THISWORD-THIS-WORD.html http://domain.com/somecategory/newurl-for-this-page.html

2) RedirectMatch permanent someurl-THISWORD-THIS-WORD.html http://domain.com    

3) RedirectMatch permanent anotherurl-THISWORD-THIS-WORD.html http://domain.com/new-anotherurl.html
```

The problem was:

Redirecting the first url (1) would cause the seond and third url (2 and 3) to be redirected to the 1) redirect (i.e. http://domain.com/somecategory/newurl-for-this-page.html )

I'd like to understand why 2nd and 3rd followed the 1st directive?

The interim solution was to give up the first redirect. So when a cleint request old url 1, they will get 404 error

is there a way to solve this through the .htaccess?

Why is this happening?

What is the logic of having 3 urls that end with the same path

i.e.

oneword-THIS-PATH.html

twoword-THIS-PATH.html

thrreword-THIS-PATH.html

that are being redirected from the same .htaccess file?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

I don't use RedirectMatch.

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/THISWORD-THIS-WORD.html
RewriteRule ^http://domain.com/somecategory/newurl-for-this-page.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/someurl-THISWORD-THIS-WORD.html
RewriteRule ^http://domain.com [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/anotherurl-THISWORD-THIS-WORD.html
RewriteRule ^http://domain.com/new-anotherurl.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am getting a 404 error  Perhaps I am missing some mod in server?